# How to set charset to utf-8 on xpages?

Tags: xpages

I would like to set the charset on my xpage to utf-8. I tried to do this via the theme design element:

```
<resources>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    </resources>
```

but it gets completely ignored.

Other meta data settings like:

```
<metaData name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

work fine.

I must have overlooked something?

Answer (score 0):

Add the encoding specification through the `xsp.properties` file:

`xsp.html.page.encoding=utf-8`

And to the `.theme` file you are using add:

```
    <resources>
        <metaData>
            <name>charset</name>
            <content>utf-8</content>
        </metaData>
        
        ...
```